# How to reuse common pattern in multiple regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, dry

Is it possible to write such instruction by writing only once `BCC Fans community` ?

```
if (document.title.match(/(.+?) - BCC Fans community$/)) {
    document.title = document.title.match(/(.+?) - BCC Fans community$/)[1]
} else if (document.title.match(/^BCC Fans community - (.+)/)) {
    document.title = document.title.match(^/BCC Fans community - (.+)/)[1]
}
```

Comment: Just combine your regex into `^BCC Fans community - (.+)|(.+?) - BCC Fans community$` and then your result is `m[1]||m[2]` if `m`

Comment: @ctwheels This is useful in addition to Eric's answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write them as string and then use new `RegExp(_STRING_);` see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)